# ERROR: _block_literal_generic or _block_invoke

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm having an issue finding the source of this crash in my iOS app which has a core data model using iPhone app i am not able to login URl. I am using same code on iOS 7 its working but now I am trying to work on iOS 8.2.Have issue for  _block_literal_generic

[image]

Block point is below As well check screen shot for  block Error:---

**[[NetwokManager sharedInstance] loginRequestEmail:userEmail andPassword:userPassword WithResponse:^(id responseObject, NSError *error) { if (!error) {
}**

Using code is below:

```
-(void)sendLoginRequest
{
    NSString *userEmail = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"emailKey"];
    NSString *userPassword = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"passwordKey"];
    NSLog(@"Email %@", userEmail);
    NSLog(@"Password %@", userPassword);
    NSString *mobileNo = [SCUserProfile currentUser].callerid;
    NSLog(@"CallerID %@", mobileNo);
    [[NetwokManager sharedInstance] loginRequestEmail:userEmail andPassword:userPassword WithResponse:^(id responseObject, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {

            NSLog(@"responseString = %@", responseObject);

            if (responseObject == nil)
            {
                NSLog(@"No data from server");

                UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                                    message:@"No data downloaded from server!"
                                                                   delegate:nil
                                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                          otherButtonTitles: nil];
                [alertView show];

            }

            NSDictionary *resposneDict = (NSDictionary*)responseObject;
            NSString *success = [resposneDict valueForKey:@"success"];
            if ([success isEqual:@"Authentication Failed"])
            {
                [self showAlertViewWithMessage:@"Authentication Failed"];
                // [self sendLogoutRequest];
                [[C2CallAppDelegate appDelegate] logoutUser];

            }
            else if ([success intValue] == 1)
            {
                amobilePayUserID = [resposneDict valueForKey:@"user_id"];
                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:amobilePayUserID forKey:@"AMobilePay_User_ID"];
                NSLog(@"User Id is:= %@",amobilePayUserID);
            }
            else if ([success intValue] == 0)
            {
                //[self sendRegistrationRequest];
                // [self sendLogoutRequest];
                // [[C2CallAppDelegate appDelegate] logoutUser];
            }
            else
            {
                [self showAlertViewWithMessage:@"Unable to login AmobilePay"];
            }
        } else {
            [self showAlertViewWithMessage:[error localizedDescription]];
        }
    }];
}
```

Comment: Hello RMaddy, can you solve this one? I am waiting to forward reply from your side.Thank you.

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: Crash in unknown region
2015-04-30 09:56:18.390 AmobipayMerchant[337:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MOC2CallEvent costs]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x16ef2dd0'

Comment: Crash in unknown region
2015-04-30 09:56:18.390 AmobipayMerchant[337:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MOC2CallEvent costs]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x16ef2dd0'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Crash in unknown region 2015-04-30 09:56:18.390 AmobipayMerchant[337:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MOC2CallEvent costs]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x16ef2dd0'

Somewhere in the code, you called `costs` to an instance of `MOC2CallEvent`. `MOC2CallEvent` has no method or property `costs`, so of course it will crash.

Comment: Thank you. But actually problem  C2Call SDK was not support to those code.Just I have update latest SDK. working fine.